# Determine the emplacement of a shared library dependence at compile time

Tags: compiling, path

Is it possible to tell at compile time a binary to be built the paths where a given library is going to be found at runtime? For example, when I link against a shared library in a non-standard location, when I want to run the resulting binary, I have to add the path to that shared library to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and I want to know whether there exists an option that spares that step and lets the binary know the location of the shared library at run time.

Ubuntu 14.04, GCC.

Comment: Do you want to specify the library location itself or just specify values that you would give to LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: Can you please tag the operating system and compiler? That would be very useful to others

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible, by adding `-Wl,-rpath,'/path/to/library'` to the arguments to GCC.  This will tell the linker to run `-rpath '/path/to/library'` when it is called.

Typically, you add this for most autoconf-based make files by adding

```
LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath=/path/to/library
```

To your environment when compiling.

As usual, [wikipedia’s RPATH article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) has all the details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The steps depend on the compiler and linker that are used.

For the GNU cc compiler, adding `-Wl,-rpath=/home/me/lib` will add /home/me/lib to the places to search at runtime for the libraries that need to be linked.